# OCaml Opam switch

Tags: ocaml, opam

I tried to switch my version of OCaml with opam but, when I wrote `opam switch 4.03.0`, it returns me that it's a invalid compiler. I also tried opam update...

My current ocaml version : 4.02.3.

My current opam version : 1.2.2.

My current distribution : debian

Notes : when I try to do `opam update` I get this :

```
opam update : =-=- Updating package repositories =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[default] synchronized from opam.ocaml.org/1.2.2
```

And with `opam switch` :

```
opam switch 4.03.0 : [ERROR] "4.03.0" is not a valid compiler
```

With `opam switch list --all` I have system C system  System compiler (4.02.3)

```
[WARNING] The environment is not in sync with the current switch.
          You should run: eval `opam config env`
```

Ok now Opam is updated but when I type `opam switch 4.07.0` I have this return : `bash: make: command not found`

Comment: Hey again. Could you add the output of `opam update` and `opam switch 4.03.0` ?

Comment: Opam update : =-=- Updating package repositories =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[default] synchronized from https://opam.ocaml.org/1.2.2


Opam switch 4.03.0 :
[ERROR] "4.03.0" is not a valid compiler.

Comment: You can add this directly as an edit to the question. Is it normal that you write Opam with a capital O in your command?

Comment: Also knowing your distribution could be useful.

Comment: Yes sorry, It's just in comments that I use Opam instead of opam

Comment: xfce isn't a distribution but a desktop environment. (try `cat /etc/os-release` to know, I think you're using Debian but I could be wrong).

Comment: Also, just showing us the result of `opam switch` could help us. You can use Ctrl+K to easily format a selected chunk of code.

Comment: `opam switch list --all` should list all locally known switches, which are the ones you can install. If it is empty or `4.03.0` is not there, then it probably means an issue with the files, or that `opam update` did not succeed.

Comment: Okey, when I use your command, I have this issue : 
system C system  System compiler (4.02.3)

[WARNING] The environment is not in sync with the current switch.
          You should run: eval `opam config env`

Comment: This is unrelated, but you didn't install OCaml through opam :-p this delay in Debian stable is always infuriating.

Comment: As a side note, try again after running `eval $(opam config env)`. This should not work but at least you'll get rid of that warning.

Comment: What does it mean ? 
It doesn't work :/

Comment: What should I do now ? @PatJ

Comment: As anol said, show us the output of `opam switch list --all` (in your question).

Comment: It seems like your `opam update` didn't work. That's puzzling. Try `mv ~/.opam ~/.opam.bak` then `opam init`, `opam update`, `opam switch list --all`. (put the output in your question)

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: as root (or preceded with `sudo`): `apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: It work ! Thanks